# If else statements works but logic seems flawed. Explain please?

Tags: c++, if-statement

This is a program I made for an assignment thats supposed to find the min and max of 3 numbers. The program works when I run it this way but I'm having trouble following the logic of why.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{

    double num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3 = 0, max = 0, min = 0;


    cout << "CMPSC 201-Lab4 " << endl << "Find max and min among 3 numbers" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter 3 numbers seperated by a space: ";
    cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3;

    min = num1;
    if (num2 < min)
    {
        min = num2;
    }
    else
    {
        min = num3;
    }

    max = num1;
    if (num2 > max)
    {
        max = num2;
    }
    else
    {
        max = num3;
    }

    cout << endl; 
    cout << "The smallest number among (" << num1 << "," << num2 << "," << num3 << ",";//Outputs the numbers entered and displays min
    cout << ") is " << min << endl;
    cout << "The largest number among (" << num1 << "," << num2 << "," << num3 << ",";//Outputs the numbers entered and displays max
    cout << ") is " << max << endl;

    return 0;
```

Heres the code for the program. The way i thought about it was setting the first of the three numbers as the min, then using the if statements to change the min variable depending on the value of the other numbers. This works with any combination of 3 numbers in varying sequence.

A problem I see is that if the statement is true then the min WILL be number 2 because the first part of the if-else will execute.But say number 3 was smaller how would it become the min since that part of the if-else wont happen. This would make sense if the code was if-else if but it is not.

So am I not seeing something or does having it like this somehow make it an if- else if statement. Sorry if this is confusing im not sure how to word it any better.

Comment: Imagine if num = 3, num2 = 2 and num3 = 1.

Answer (score 5):

```
min = num1;
if (num2 < min)
{
    min = num2;
}
else
{
    min = num3;
}
```

This cannot possibly work, because `min` will never be `num1`; it is immediately overwritten by either `num2` or `num3`.

One `if` statement gives the control flow two choices in your program, which is not enough. Since this is an exercise, I'll leave the rest to figure out for yourself ;)

Comment: I would add an image of this working if I could but I havent made enough posts. I assure you though it works the way it's supposed with any combination of numbers including num1 being the min which is why im confused.

Comment: Have you tried the input `1 2 3`? The program says the smallest number is 3, and the biggest number is 2. If that's "it works the way it's supposed", then I don't understand the spec.

Comment: Sorry, now I see what happened. When I switched to a different project to test the way I currently have posted, I was actually still starting the old one(formatted the way Jerome L explained) that was logically sound. That made me think It was working both ways.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing some comparison between `num3` and `min`. Before assigning `num3` to `min`, you want to make sure that `num3` is actually the minimum.

You also need to remove the `else` here because you want to do both comparison `num2 < min` and `num3 < min`

```
min = num1;
if (num2 < min)
{
    min = num2;
}
if (num3 < min)
{
    min = num3;
}

max = num1;
if (num2 > max)
{
    max = num2;
}
if (num3 > max)
{
    max = num3;
}
```